# Find current and previous node hovered

Tags: javascript, frontend

I have an html list that contains children with links. I want to find the current element that is hovered, and also the previously hovered one. (Not the previous sibling of the one currently hovered, just the item that was hovered until the current).

Thanks

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706701/getting-id-of-any-tag-when-mouseover

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store it in a global variable:

```js
var hoveredElement; // We'll store our "previous" data here

// Add a hover listener to the UL, then delegate to the anchors 
document.querySelector('ul').addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
  if (e.target && e.target.matches('a')) {
    
    // If we have a previous hovered element, add it
    if (hoveredElement) {
      document.querySelector('.previous').textContent = hoveredElement
    }

    // Set the current hovered and the "new" last hovered elements to the currently hovered element
    document.querySelector('.current').textContent = hoveredElement = e.target.textContent
  }
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Item 1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Item 2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Item 3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<hr />
<p>Current: <span class="current"></span></p>
<p>Previous: <span class="previous"></span></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to store the element when the mouse leaves it, and on mouse enter check what it is. For example:

```
var previous;

$('div').on('mouseleave',function(event){
    previous = $(this);
});

$('div').on("mouseenter", function(event){
    console.log($(this).text(), previous.text());
})
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lmcs0cqv/)

Answer (score 0):

**Pure JavaScript**

```js
var previouslyHovered
var currentlyHovered
var previousBox = document.querySelector('.previouslyHovered')
var currentBox = document.querySelector('.currentlyHovered')

var items = document.querySelectorAll('li')

items.forEach(item => item.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  previouslyHovered = currentlyHovered
  previousBox.textContent = previouslyHovered
    ?previouslyHovered.textContent
    :previousBox.textContent
  
  currentlyHovered = this
  currentBox.textContent = currentlyHovered.textContent
}))
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
</ul>
<div>previous
<span class="previouslyHovered">n/a</span>
</div>
<div>current
<span class="currentlyHovered">n/a</span>
</div>
```